# ReactJS, создать новый элемент на странице

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как при нажатии на кнопку (страницу уже зарендерина) создать элемент?

Пример:

```
// Нужно добавить данный элемент
<div> 
    <h1>Все сломалось</h1>
</div>

... // Контент сайта 

<button onClick={save_data}>Сохранить</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создай state, в котором будет храниться состояние, например, `{ broken: false }`.
2. В render добавь условие, если `broken == true`, отображаем блок с ошибкой.
3. На кнопку повесь обработчик с setState.

Comment: Как я понял вот так?

`<div>{this.broken ?<NewComponent/> : null}</div>`, а при повторном нажатии на кнопку это будет новый элемент или старый?

Comment: `{ this.state.broken ? <NewComponent/> : null }`

Comment: ага, спасибо, а при повторном изменении `this.state.broken`  элемент `<NewComponent/>` обновиться?

Comment: да, при изменении состояния вызывается  render

Comment: спасибо, то есть если в renader был не только `NewComponent` будут еще заново созданы все элементы в этом блоке?

Comment: да, так работает react, поэтому старайся разделять свои компоненты